# Warning while trying to add mapping with dynamic_templates having analyzer and search_analyzer

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using elasticsearch python client to connect to elasticsearch.

While trying to add mapping to index, I am getting following warning:

```
es.indices.put_mapping(index=index, body=mappings)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py:209: ElasticsearchWarning: }}], attempted to validate it with the following match_mapping_type: [string], caused by [unknown parameter [search_analyzer] on mapper [__dynamic__attributes] of type [keyword]]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py:209: ElasticsearchWarning: }}], attempted to validate it with the following match_mapping_type: [string], caused by [unknown parameter [search_analyzer] on mapper [__dynamic__metadata] of type [keyword]]
  warnings.warn(message, category=ElasticsearchWarning)
```

And while indexing the record, got this warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py:209: ElasticsearchWarning: Parameter [search_analyzer] is used in a dynamic template mapping and has no effect on type [keyword]. Usage will result in an error in future major versions and should be removed.
  warnings.warn(message, category=ElasticsearchWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py:209: ElasticsearchWarning: Parameter [analyzer] is used in a dynamic template mapping and has no effect on type [keyword]. Usage will result in an error in future major versions and should be removed.
  warnings.warn(message, category=ElasticsearchWarning)
```

I am using Using elasticsearch "7.15.1"

pip packages:

elasticsearch==7.15.1

elasticsearch-dsl==7.4.0

My settings and mappings are:

```
settings = {"analysis": {"analyzer": {"my_analyzer": {
                                      "type": "custom",
                                      "tokenizer": "keyword",
                                      "filter": ["trim"]}
                                      }
                         }
            }
mappings = {"dynamic_templates": [
                            {"attributes": {
                                "match_mapping_type": "string",
                                "path_match": "attributes.*",
                                "mapping": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                                    "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                                    }
                                }
                             },
                            {"metadata": {
                                "match_mapping_type": "string",
                                "path_match": "metadata.*",
                                "mapping": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                                    "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                                    }
                                }
                             }
                        ]
            }
```

I need help in adjusting the mapping, this mapping was working fine on elastic 6.0.1. After upgrading to 7.15.1 started getting warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set an analyzer on a **keyword** field. The [Elasticsearch analyzer documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html) states at the top of the page:

> Only **text** fields support the analyzer mapping parameter.

You have to change the type of your field to text or specify no analyzer at all for the keyword fields. You can also use [normalizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/analysis-normalizers.html#analysis-normalizers) to apply token filters to your keyword fields. As mentioned in the answer from this [question](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cannot-use-custom-analyzer-for-keyword/95813) on the Elastic discuss page.

The trim token filter that you want to use is not explicitly mentioned in the list of compatible filters, but I tried it with the Kibana dev tools, and it seems to work:

```
PUT normalizer_trim
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": ["lowercase", "trim"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "foo": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it. I want my field `keyword` only, since want to do exact match and not want break text  for searching. Then how can I use `trim` `filter` with `type` `keyword`. I want to remove leading and trailing spaces while indexing and searching.

Comment: Token filters can be applied to keyword fields with normalizers, i adjusted my answer to include this information.